# When mining a block reward, does it have to have an ip address present in order to complete the reward

Tags: mining-reward

When mining a block reward, Does it (The reward provider)have to have an IP Address/Computer Connected to Internet) present in the whole process in order to complete the reward on the block chain.What i am asking is it possible to mine a block reward with no internet access.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `reward provider`, the Bitcoin network itself manages that. Miner doesn't have to publish anything about themselves, all we need is a block and a valid PoW. Miners pay themselves with a specific transaction inside a block, called coinbase transaction.
You can mine with no internet access, but if you want to mine a Bitcoin block and get reward from that, you'll have two problems:

- How to get data to build a block and mine.
- How to broadcast your block after you mine it.

If you solve both problems, you can mine offline.

Answer (score 1):

When building a block template, each miner includes a coinbase transaction which assigns the block reward to an address of the miner's choosing. When they find a block, their coinbase transaction becomes a part of the blockchain and the miner pays themselves.

Contributing to Bitcoin mining requires internet to learn about the previous block, unconfirmed transactions, and to broadcast blocks found. You could perform mining without internet, if you're not actually participating in a P2P such as when running a testnet locally.

Comment: Thankyou ,just as i thought much appreciated.